# Copy specific files from drive C: to a folder on Desktop

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, permissionerror

I need to walk through entire C:\ hard drive and take copy of all .jpg .mp3, mp4 and .avi files from Windows hard drive C: to Backup folder on desktop

```
import os.path
import shutil

#Create Directory if don't exist in Desktop path
dir_name = "abc"
dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
#dir_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, dir_name)

if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.mkdir(file_path)
    print(file_path)

  
extensions = [".mp3", ".mpeg", ".mp4", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".avi"]

src_path = r"C:\\"
dst_dir = file_path
for root, dirs,files in os.walk(src_path):
   for file in extensions:
      if file.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
         shutil.copy(file_path, dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write:

```
shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, file), file_path)

import os
import shutil

#Create Directory if don't exist in Desktop path
dir_name = "Backup"

dir_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
#dir_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, dir_name)

if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    os.mkdir(file_path)
    print(file_path)

path = r'C:\\'
extensions = [".png", ".mp3", ".mpeg", ".mp4", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".avi"]
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(tuple(extensions)):
            shutil.copy2(os.path.join(root, file), file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
src_path = r'C:\\', encoding='utf-8'
```

or

chmod 777 "your file"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: src_path = r'C:\\', encoding='utf-8'
              ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Comment: can ? chmod 777 "your file"

Comment: But I'm using windows!

Comment: You mean os.mkdir(file_path, 777) ?